# iPhone SDK: Interact with Images

Tags: iphone

I was making an app for the iPhone and part of what I want to do is that whenever the user touches a certain spot (let's say a circle), the app should react and do something.

How do I pinpoint that one spot as a button? Or is there a different way to do this? I have a UIScrollView with a subview of a UIImageView.

Thanks in advance!

Guy

Answer (score 2):

You can learn how to handle touch from the [Touches](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435) sample.

In particular, handling a simple touch happens in instances of the [`UIResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Since `UIView` inherits from `UIResponder`, any view is capable of responding to the touch messages. Thus, in order to handle touch, you just need to create a class that inherits from the particular view (`UIScrollView` in your case) and overwrite the touch invent you are interested; more specifically, for your scenario you need to handle the [`touchesEnded:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-SW3).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is add some transparent UIButton instances on UIScrollView, set actions and do something in each button.

for example,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch

...

UIButton* someButton = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)] autorelease];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[someUIScrollView addSubview:someButton];

...
}

- (void)doSomething {
    NSLog(@"Do something");
}
```

You should write some codes for judging whether touched point is inside or not, if you want to create non-rect spot (such as circle). But considering finger size and user recognition, I think you don't have to implement a strict judgement.